# Cambiar de tamaño gridview eventos AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

tengo un griview ASP.NET que tiene 2 de sus columnas congelas y su header congelado.

Para que ésto suceda he ocupado un jquery puglin libre que encontré en la web.

Mi problema radica en qué tan responsivo es éste. Cuando hago zoom in ó zoom out la griview se quedaba con su tamaño original aunque ésta tuviera clase de bootstrap  y ésto pq el jquery paraliza a la tabla estáticamente. Lo he solucionado con el evento windows.resize

```
 $(window).resize(function () {        
     var B_width = $("#balance").width();
     var B_height = $("#balance").height();
     gridviewScrollBalance(B_width, B_height);
     refreshGrid();
  });
```

El #balance es un div con clase de bootstrap "col-md-12" así que éste recoge el dato "width" para mi evento posterior.

En sí cuando hago un resize , la tabla está respondiendo y casi que ajustando al marco de mi web inicial...digo casi pq es aquí el problema nuevo, si yo lo tengo al 100% el zoom del browser y hago un zoom out a un 60%, entonces mi tabla se ajusta al cuerpo central de mi web, pero se genera un espacio extra en blanco al lado derecho del cuerpo de la web... si abro mi tool developer me indica el valor de un margen del jqueryplugin anterior al zoom (o sea el 100%). Si hago un refresh al div la web se compone y queda todo bien...pero siento que toma demasiado tiempo en cargar de la caché

Estoy ocupando esto en jQuery:

```
 $(window).resize(function () {        
     var B_width = $("#balance").width();
     var B_height = $("#balance").height();
     gridviewScrollBalance(B_width, B_height);
     window.location = window.location.href + "#balance";
     window.location.reload(false);        
 });
```

Para no confundirlos el "gridviewScrollBalance" es para editar la gridview a como necesito luego de esto intento refrescar el div que lo contiene... pero siento muy desfasada esta solución. es una grid mediana con 250 celdas de info que para un ordendor no se si sea mucho trabajo procesarlo, es algo pequeña.

Hice éste intento con AJAX, pero creo que estoy haciendolo mal, trato de refrescar el div a través de ajax:

```
   function refreshGrid() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "Inicio.aspx",

         type: "GET",
         dataType: "html",
         success: function (data) {
             var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#balance').html();
             $('#balance').html(result);
         },
         error: function (xhr, status) {

         },
         complete: function (xhr, status) {
             $('#balance').html(result);
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Acabo de intentar : document.getElementById('balance').contentWindow.location.reload(true); lo que me funcionó muy bien, pero el developer tool de chrome me lanza un error como éste: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined. Pensé que éste DOM busca elementos ASP, le puse el id del grid asp pero el mismo error recibe, aunque es funcional. Pero no me gusta que de error behind the code, porque algo puede pasar después.

Answer (score 0):

No te compliques, carga la grid, con los datos, una vez cargado el html dale formato con jtables, es un plugin de que usa jquery.  En jtables viene la configuracion responsive y el compatible con bootstrap. Tambien viene la configuracion con $.ajax si quieres modificar en tiempo real,  pero te sugiero el tradicional $(target).append(codigo);
En aspx solo carga la grid, darle formato desde el servidor es complicado, por eso cuando ya este cargada te haces un metodo $(document).ready() u onload()

Comment: Fíjate que usé ésto:   var ER_ = document.getElementById('GVERASP'); //Get the div to refresh
        ER_.src = ER_.src  //Refresh DOM  me funcionó genial;sin el error que mecioné anterirormente. Gracias por tu propuesta indagaré sobre el tema haber que tal.